# How to determine point at distance along perpendicular bearing using javascript latitude/longitude geodesy calculations?

Tags: javascript, math, latitude-longitude, geodesic-sphere

I've been using the fantastic write up and JavaScript library referred to here on [Vector-based geodesy](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vectors.html) 
for vector-based spherical LatLong point and distance calculations. It has just about all of the functions and properties I’ve needed except (as far as I can tell) the ability to determine a perpendicular bearing given a known bearing. I want to be able to identify a new point at a distance along that perpendicular bearing from a given point when I know an initial bearing through that same given point.

The background behind wanting to determine the perpendicular points is that I am working with area on the ground where I know the lat/lon of two points on the ground and and I want to draw a rectangular polygon on a map between the two known points (that are each on the midpoint of two opposite edges of the rectangle - the beginning and ending edges of the rectange), using 4 corners points that need to be calculated and a provided X width for the rectangle. I need to be determine what the 4 corner point coordinates would be. The original bearing to find the perpendicular from is simply the bearing between the two original points.

I've identified a few function signatures that “I think” would be necessary but I am not sure if this is more than just simple angular subtraction/addition as I currently have it there or if there needs to be some sort of adjustment based on the position of the given point on the globe and the bearing through that point.

```
/**
 * Determine bearing at a rotational angle from a known bearing and from ‘this’ point
 *
 * @param   {number}   bearing - Initial bearing in degrees from north.
 * @param   {number}   angle - Rotation angle in degrees (i.e. 90 or -90)
 * @returns {number} Bearing at rotation angle to provided bearing
 *
 */
LatLon.prototype.bearingAtAngle(bearing,angle) {
  # Is this simply bearing + angle and no adjustments are needed? 
  return bearing + angle;
  # Or do we need to adjust for where the point is located and the original bearing?
}
/**
 * Determine perpendicular bearing from a known bearing and rotation direction from ‘this’ point
 *
 * @param   {number}   bearing - Initial bearing in degrees from north.
 * @param   {string}   rotation - “+” or “-“ (or could be “positive”/“negative”, “clockwise”/“counterClockwise”,0/1 or something to indicate which rotational direction to use to determine the perpendicular bearing)
 * @returns {number} Bearing perpendicular to provided bearing and direction 
 *
 */
LatLon.prototype.perpendicularBearing(bearing,rotation) {
  var angle = rotation == “+” ? 90 : -90;
  return this.bearingAtAngle(bearing,angle);
}
/**
 * Determine a point at a distance from ’this’ point along bearing that is perpendicular to a known bearing through the same point
 *
 * @param   {number}   bearing - Initial bearing in degrees from north
 * @param   {string}   rotation - “+” or “-“ (or could be “positive”/“negative”, “clockwise”/“counterclockwise”,0/1 or something to indicate which rotational direction to use to determine the perpendicular bearing)
 * @param   {number}   distance - Distance travelled, in same units as earth radius (default: metres).
 * @returns {number} Bearing perpendicular to provided bearing and direction 
 *
 */
LatLon.prototype.perpendicularPoint(bearing, rotation, distance) {
  var perpendicularBearing = this.perpendicularBearing(bearing,rotation);
  # use distance along this newly determined perpendicularBearing 
  return this.destinationPoint(distance, perpendicularBearing);
}
```

The functions I have above seem to work visually for small areas I am dealing with in my current experiments but I am not sure if I am just unable to tell the difference and when applied to a larger distance or at different orientations around the globe will it still work as expected.

**Update**

Adding an image to show what I am trying to accomplish. The two known points are at the red and green pins. I want to determine the coordinates for the corners of the purple box.

[image]

Comment: If you "want to draw a rectangular polygon on a map between the two known points" you should use those points' projected coordinates to determine the rectangle's corners as projected coordinates and then unproject the corners back to latitude and longitude. And, of course, the rectangle will only look like a rectangle on maps using that projection.

Comment: Hi @cartant, thanks for the comment. I can see that I didn't clarify that the 2 known points are each on the midpoint of two opposite edges of the rectangle, and not the corners of the rectangle. I updated the post to clarify this now.

Comment: @cartant, I just added an image to further clarify the goal. The two known points are the red and green pins. I want to determine the coordinates for the four corners of the purple rectangle. I believe the solution / code above is doing that now and the visual of the image seems to back that up with this small example. Just not sure if it still holds true anywhere on globe and at much larger rectangles.